# Cambiar color de texto del headerTCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Buen día colegas, necesito una ayuda
¿Cómo puedo cambiar el color de cabecera del siguiente reporte generado mediante TCPDF?, estoy usando Codeigniter y no logro poder cambiar el color por default del texto de cabecera TCPDF, agradezco su gentil ayuda, saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tienes que cambiar la fuente en las funciones públicas **Header()** y **Footer()** en `tcpdf.php`. Para encontrar el color del texto:

```
$this->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
```

En las funciones Header() y/o Footer() y cámbialo a tu gusto.

En cuanto al color de la línea, encuentre:

```
$this->SetLineStyle(array('width' => 0.85 / $this->k, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(70, 70, 70)));
```

Y cambie el conjunto de 'colores' al final.

---

O alternativamente puedes hacerlo de esta manera también:

Al extender la clase principal y extender solo su función Footer():

```
// Extienda la clase TCPDF para crear encabezado y pie de página personalizados
class MYPDF extends TCPDF 
{
   // Pie de página
   public function Footer() 
   {
      //establecer el color del texto
      $this->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
    }
}
// crear nuevo documento PDF
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

> Fuente SO: [Change text color in header in TCPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109280/change-text-color-in-header-in-tcpdf)